# Reading binary data with fstream method

Tags: c++, c, char, fstream, unsigned-char

I need to read binary data to buffer, but in the fstreams I have read function reading data into **char** buffer, so my question is:

How to transport/cast binary data into **unsigned char** buffer and is it best solution in this case?

Example

```
  char data[54];
  unsigned char uData[54];
  fstream file(someFilename,ios::in | ios::binary);
  file.read(data,54);
  // There to transport **char** data into **unsigned char** data (?)
  // How to?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read it into unsigned char data in the first place

```
unsigned char uData[54];
fstream file(someFilename,ios::in | ios::binary);
file.read((char*)uData, 54);
```

The cast is necessary but harmless.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare the extra array uData. The data array can simply be cast to unsigned:

```
unsigned char* uData = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data);
```

When accessing uData you instruct the compiler to interpret the data different, for example data[3] == -1, means uData[3] == 255

Comment: Although a `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data)` works and is, as far as I know, portable using `static_cast<unsigned char*>(data)` does _not_ work. ... and I think your last statement is not correct in general: for one, `char` may be `unsigned` and I don't think two's complement is strictly required.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use

```
std::copy(data, data + n, uData);
```

where `n` is the result returned from `file.read(data, 54)`. I *think*, specifically for `char*` and `unsigned char*` you can also portably use

```
std::streamsize n = file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(uData));
```